# Доступ к скриптам из других папок

Tags: .htaccess, php, include, require

Приветствую!
Подскажите, можно ли реализовать такую задачу.
Имеется папка, например, User1, нужно сделать так, чтобы вызов файла, находящегося вне этой папки, был невозможен. Иными словами, `include('../lib/abc.php');` или `unlink();` не срабатывали, за исключением тех файлов и папок, что находятся в текущей директории пользователя.

Comment: Если разрешено изменять open_basedir, то в каждой папке создаем htaccess и пишем в него строку php_value    open_basedir    /var/www/foo.bar/:/usr/local/php/.

Comment: К сожалению, нельзя, есть ли какая-нибудь альтернатива?

Comment: @Cript, вообще, указанный вами функционал - это либо chroot, либо разрешения на папку для единственного юзера. Другое дело, что при чруте понадобится зоопарк симлинков и поднятый php внутри каждой темницы, при втором варианте будет зоопарк пользователей.

Comment: Хотя вот еще решение: все файлы и папки создаются от Темного Пользователя Х, разрешения на модифкацию выданы только ему. На сервере крутится демон Темного Пользователя Х, который осуществляет указанный функционал своими кастомными функциями, а include/require/chmod/mkdir и прочий зоопарк оказывается запрещен.

Comment: "разрешения на папку для единственного юзера" можно поподробнее?
На счет Темного Пользователя Х не совсем понимаю что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: @Cript, есть пользователь, который владеет всеми папками, и в которые может писать/читать (кроме index.php) только он. Вся интеракция с файлами проводится через приложение, запущенное от его имени, которое и фильтрует запросы.

Answer (score 1):

Для каждой папки User(User1, user2 etc) создавайте конфигурационный файл, в котором указывайте `$secret_key` - уникальный ключ для каждой директории, а также в имя самого файла добавляйте этот ключ (прим. `$secret_key = 'dhJYmnk87asd';  config_dhJYmnk87asd.php`). В любом из файлов, запускаемых в директории пользователя, первоначально инклудится файл конфигурации, после чего сверяется `$secret_key`. Получается, что пользователь, не зная ключ другого пользователя, не сможет ни подключить конфиг другого пользователя, и ни пройти проверку на ключ.
По поводу унлинк надо думать. Но как вариант в названия всех пользовательских файлов добавлять `$secret_key`. Получить доступ или удалить можно только методом долгого подбора. Но в таком случае можно поставить проверку на множественные вызовы и блокировать аккаунт пользователя.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Интересный вариант, однако тут важнее предотвратить unlink. Изменять названия файлов точно не вариант.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, для чего Вам такие телодвижения? upd и уточните - у Вас обычный хостинг или свой сервер?